Binary Space Partitioning Tree Implementation
Does anyone have or know where to find an example of the Python BSP-Tree implementation? I am doing a comparison between the K-d tree and the BSP tree and their runtime based on an NN search. (After getting an implementation I will modify it to the same configs)
I managed to find a self-balancing K-D tree implementation by a very nice researcher who opened it to the public (I know BSP is a generalization, but I just can't seem to modify the K-D tree to get it working), but I just can't seem to find one for the BSP tree.
Sorry if some of the things I said were quite inaccurate please do correct me as I am writing a paper on this ;-;
Perhaps I am simply blind but I just can't seem to find a proper Python implementation. All the times I have found something, they were simple conceptual implementations or fractions of the actual tree

To implement a BSP tree in Python, start with a K-D tree and modify it to allow arbitrary splitting planes rather than axis-aligned ones. You'll need to:
Use a method like Principal Component Analysis  to find the optimal plane for splitting the points.
Divide the points into two sets based on which side of the plane they lie on.
Build the tree recursively by splitting the points at each node.
For NN search, adapt the K-D tree algorithm to consider the arbitrary planes. If you need a starting point, adapting a K-D tree implementation is your best option since BSP-specific Python implementations are rare.
